# Redactor has destroyed my mailto links, now what?

Tags: redactor, emails, filtering

I migrated from EE > CraftCMS. The email links in my EE WYGWAM fields were encoded as JS. When we imported to CraftCMS we lost all of those links. They now look like this:

```
<a>joe@schmoe.com</a>
```

Any ideas on how I could fix this? Perhaps I can pass my Redactor field through a filter that looks for an email pattern, and use Retcon to rewrap the link?

I'm looking for a solution that does not involve reimporting my data, as it's not an option at this point.

Comment: Have you find any solution?

Comment: @kemsky, I ended up using JS to solve the problem. I’m targeting a pattern that matches an email address and rewriting it on page load.